# Duplicate Groups Based On Date

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

i have the following query that detects duplicates based on the RegNumber column value and if the different row entry dates differ by less than 10 minutes, the query keeps the one with the highest Confidence column value.

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE 
         WHEN conf_max = confidence THEN 'Conf_Max' 
         ELSE 'Duplicate' 
       END AS Is_Conf_Max 
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               Max(confidence) 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY regnumber) AS Conf_Max 
        FROM   (SELECT id, 
                       cameraid, 
                       dateseen, 
                       nationality, 
                       regnumber, 
                       confidence, 
                       Min(dateseen) 
                         OVER ( 
                           partition BY regnumber) AS DateSeen_Min, 
                       Max(dateseen) 
                         OVER ( 
                           partition BY regnumber) AS DateSeen_Max 
                FROM   plate_read 
                WHERE  ( cameraid IN ( 5, 6 ) )) A 
        WHERE  Abs(Datediff(minute, dateseen_max, dateseen_min)) <= 10) B 
WHERE  conf_max <> confidence 
ORDER  BY regnumber
```

However the problem is as follows: this gives me all duplicates where the DateSeen column differs by less than 10 minutes. However if i then have another group of duplicates more than 10 min apart and with the same RegNumber these are not detected example as follows:

```
ID    CamId     DateSeen                 Nationality   Reg      Conf
--    -----     -------                 ----------     ---      ---
80      5    20/12/2013 12:10:57           E         5897HHS     94
81      5    20/12/2013 12:15:03           E         5897HHS     93
82      5    20/12/2013 12:16:17          GBZ        G6746D      98
83      5    20/12/2013 12:35:57           E         5897HHS     88
84      5    20/12/2013 12:36:03           E         5897HHS     86
```

From this data above only ID 80, 82 and 83 are valid as 81 is a duplicate of 80 and 84 is a duplicate of 83. Hopefully someone can assist with this?

Comment: sorry new member not exactly sure how to do it...trying to.

Comment: thanks Mihai. Hopefully someone can help me with my question now.

Comment: So why dont you modify the minutes to select for a wider range?

Comment: Because if it is over 10 minutes apart then it is no longer a duplicate it is another valid entry.

Comment: you can have two entries that are perhaps 6 minutes apart with the same reg number, this creates 1 duplicate. half an hour later if the same reg number is seen it is valid but once again and more duplicates  may exist etc.

Comment: Not certain, but I'm thinking you might have to pull this out in to a stored proc and use a cursor / some temporary tables for that kind of comparison otherwise it may get messy.

Comment: Yes possibly i will have to go down that route, i am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your CASE expression isn't adding anything atm (you always get 'Duplicate'), because of your WHERE clause filtering the opposite rows, just saying..

Comment: Yes i know..currently i am just listing rows which the system deems as duplicates.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete answer, but why does your query need to be so complicated? Why not simplify it to this (extra criteria omitted for clarity):

```
select *
from plate_read pr1
where conf = (
  select max (conf)
  from plate_read pr2
  where pr1.reg = pr2.reg
  and abs(datediff(minute,pr1.dateseen,pr2.dateseen)) < 11
  )
```

As saved [in SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16c50/6).